# Two linux kernels show up in rEFInd

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, refind

rEFInd gives me the options to boot `3.13.0-32-generic` and `3.13.0-34-generic`. Is it possible/practical to either uninstall the old one, or prevent it from showing up in the bootloader.

Thank you for your help!

- /u/rossistboss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend leaving at least two kernels installed. The reason is that the redundancy can be helpful in case one kernel file (or its associated RAM disk file) is damaged. If this happens, you should still be able to use the other file to boot the computer.

That said, you *can* delete old kernel packages. I recommend using `dpkg` for this task rather than just brute-force deleting the files. If you get more than two or three kernels, you can remove all but two or three of them by typing `sudo apt-get autoremove`. (I don't recall offhand if that leaves two or three in place.)

Comment: Ok. I will leave them both installed. Thank you for the reply. I am glad that someone managed to find this old question!